# Using Record for inserting Data PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I was trying to insert a record into dept_new table, which contains 2 columns,

```
DEPT_NAME         VARCHAR2(30)  
DEPT_ID        VARCHAR2(255)
```

Another table dept is there from which the record dept_e is created.

```
ACCEPT dept_num VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL PROMPT 'Enter dept_id: ';

DECLARE
   dept_e dept%ROWTYPE;
   dept_no := &dept_num;

BEGIN
   select * INTO dept_e 
     from dept
    where dept_id = dept_no;

   INSERT INTO dept_new(dept_id,dept_name)
     VALUES (dept_e.dept_id, dept_e.dept_name);

   COMMIT;
END;
/


Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

constant exception <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table LONG_ double ref
char time timestamp interval date binary national character
nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Got it, dept_no varchar2(255) not null := &dept_num;

Comment: +1 - found own answer.

Comment: You've got three names for the dept_id in there -- dept_num, dept_no, and dept_id. Give your PL/SQL block a name, using <<my_block_name>>, use my_block_name.dept_id as the name for the PL/SQL variable, &dept_id for the SQL*Plus variable. Your code will be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the data type for the variable

```
 dept_no := &dept_num;
```

as below

```
dept_no number := &dept_num;
```

hope this will solve your problem